# Issue with PHP rtrim

Tags: php, string, substring

```
  <?php 

    $FacilitatorListStr = "Andrew Langmoir,<br/>";
    $FacilitatorListStr = rtrim($FacilitatorListStr , ',<br/>');
    echo $FacilitatorListStr;
    ?>
```

For the code above the output I get is `Andrew Langmoi`.It removes the character `"r"` from the string as well.But the output should be `Andrew Langmoir`.This issue is only caused with the character `"r"` only.Please help.

Comment: Because on your mask you have `,<br>` so if any of those characters show up at the end they are removed. In your case `r` is, after `,<br/>` is removed `r` becomes the last hence, is removed.

Comment: When in doubt [read the documentation](http://php.net/rtrim): *"You can also specify **the characters** you want to strip [...]"*.

Comment: try str_replace(',<br/>', '', $FacilitatorListStr);

Comment: if you want to delete tags use `strip_tags()` if you want delete spaces in the end of string use `rtrim()` and re-read the manual http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php `<br />` it's not 'whitespace` it's `html tag` =\

Comment: haha too bad I didn't make that an answer :P so many up votes. @Riturajratan is there a reason for you not to use `DOMDocument`(as it seems you're dealing with more HTML and that is just portion of the information you needed to filter after) or `str_replace`?

Comment: @Prix right comment can be up?

Comment: @RakeshSharma sorry, I don't think I understood you.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can use `str_replace` like:

```
<?php
    $FacilitatorListStr = str_replace(",<br/>","",$FacilitatorListStr );
    echo $FacilitatorListStr;
?>
```

You can check at http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php

Also as your OP is for removing at the end only note the use of the ***$ character***, which denotes the end of a string:
use it as

```
    $FacilitatorListStr = preg_replace('/\,\<br\/\>$/', '',  $FacilitatorListStr);
    echo $FacilitatorListStr;
```

Also If it is an user input string use `preg_quote` first

Comment: thanks for the reply but i need to remove the ",<br/>"  from the end of the string only.Is there any other way?

Comment: Updated the answer and you can check at the specific site i mentioned thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this,

```
<?php 

  $FacilitatorListStr = "Andrew Langmoir,<br/>";
  $FacilitatorListStr = preg_replace('/,(?:<br\s*\/?>\s*)+/', '', $FacilitatorListStr);
  echo $FacilitatorListStr;
?>
```

Wroking Code : http://codepad.org/mwCrObni

Answer (score -2):

```
  <?php 

       $FacilitatorListStr = "Andrew Langmoir,<br/>";
       $FacilitatorListStr = substr($FacilitatorListStr,strpos($FacilitatorListStr,",")); 
       echo $FacilitatorListStr;

?>
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Looks like javascript mixed with php